# Detecting screen/ application updates with python on windows

Tags: python, windows, automation, camera, surveillance

Currently I have to check cameras everyday at work, over 400 of them. I would like to automate this task. i know python is great for automation but I'm not seeing a solution, maybe my google-fu isn't good enough, I'm not sure.

Basically I just want to be able to detect when certain parts of the screen update and then use that info to fill an excel sheet. I don't want to plug into the application if possible.

Comment: This is an excessively broad question. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: i dont understand how this is broad im afraid, i stated that i want to know how to detect screen updates on a windows machine. In android you can turn on a setting to check screen updates, i wish to know how i can do that on PC.